# Combining items from several lists with pagination

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to come up with an algorithm for getting items for a news feed from several sources.

There are multiple lists of data: S1, S2, ... Sn. Each of these lists has a certain known amount of items, Q1, Q2, ... Qn. I need to show these items with pagination, with a certain amount from each list per page, P1, P2, ... Pn, with total amount of items per page T = sum(P). I get items from lists using offset and limit (in reality, they are SQL tables). Obviously, at some point i shall run out of items of a particular type, in which case i need to fill the blanks with items from other lists to get exactly T items for each page except the last one which can have less than T items.

Here's a concrete example for N=2, Q1=27, Q2=95, P1=10, P2=20, T=10+20=30:

```
==========================================================================
| Page | From S1 | S1 offset | S1 limit | From S2 | S2 offset | S2 limit |
==========================================================================
|  1   |   10    |     0     |    10    |    20   |     0     |    20    |
|  2   |   10    |    10     |    10    |    20   |    20     |    20    |
|  3   |    7    |    20     |    (7)   |    23   |    40     |    23    |
|  4   |    0    |     0     |    (0)   |    30   |    63     |    30    |
|  5   |    0    |     0     |    (0)   |     2   |    93     |    (2)   |
==========================================================================
```

The numbers in parenthesis are not really important, because i can live with asking the SQL table for more entries than it has.

Ideally, i'm looking for an algorithm that can give me offsets and limits for a given page.

Any ideas?

Comment: A few questions: 1. Do you know the number of items in each list beforehand, or only when you get fewer items back than requested? 2. If you have 3 or more lists and one list has run out, how should that free space be filled? Can that all come from one list, or should it be balanced?

Comment: 1 - Yes, i know the length beforehand. 2 - Free space should be balanced.
This algorithm can probably be implemented in a brute-force way (i.e. starting from page 1 an filling the whole table), but since the amount of items in each list is known beforehand, I feel there is a more efficient way.

Comment: I'm surprised P1, P2.. are given. If you leave them out, you just divide T proportional to Q1, Q2... (with maybe a minimum). Is that an option?

Comment: No, having a certain defined ratio of items (1:2 in the example) as long as possible is an important requirement.